# python socket - how to save stream to file

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server that sends data out to a port. In python, how can I create a script that connects to that socket, and save the data stream locally?

Comment: This is also something that could have been answered by a quick look in Python's documentation. I don't mean to discourage asking questions, but it might have been faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By a simple client socket program?

```
import socket

HOST = 'yourhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 101             # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
with open('yourfile','w') as f:
     f.write(data)
```

Further help [here.](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html)

Comment: It returns an error ```TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes```