# I am unable to simultaneously stream the feed from my RBP3's camera and record to a file at the same time using python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi3

I know how to save to a file using the code below (and timestamp the feed) and I know how to stream using uv4l but I am simply too bad to do it simultaneously.

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
import picamera
import datetime as dt

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
#camera.vflip = True
camera.led = False

x = 0

while True:


    bideoname = "/media/pi/cam/" + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H') + ".h264"
    camera.annotate_background = picamera.Color('black')
    camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording(bideoname)
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    while (dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds < 3600:
        camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        camera.wait_recording(0.2) 


    camera.stop_recording()
    x = x+1
```

I imagine I would use flask to to create local website to stream the feed to.

I have looked up and down the internets and this example seems to be the closest solution by Dave Jones but I don't if socket can communicate with a browser:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/record-and-stream-video-from-camera-simultaneously

Also there is this code which streams the camera feed to a page but no mention of how to simultanously record as well:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

# Raspberry Pi camera module (requires picamera package, developed by Miguel Grinberg)
from camera_pi import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port =80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Or maybe this is all wrong and there is simpler solution to this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This may be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474839/4902099

Comment: I appreciate the help, I suppose my question with this approach is can socket send said stream to a local network page so it can be viewed through a browser?

Comment: Web browser is using http protocol and html, socket is not. But once you understand the differences, you could make socket to emulate http to communicate with flask, or like what I did in [this blog](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/), which communicate with socket and present it in browser without a flask web framework.